# Infinite expansion of difference of squares?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, infinite-product

I was just wondering if the following is legitimate or if there's a problem with it:

Using difference of squares,

$a^n - b^n = (a^{n/2}-b^{n/2})(a^{n/2}+b^{n/2}) = (a^{n/4}-b^{n/4})(a^{n/4}+b^{n/4})(a^{n/2}+b^{n/2}) $

Continuing expanding in the same way, in general, for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$,
$a^n - b^n = (a^{n/{2^k}}-b^{n/{2^k}})(a^{n/{2^k}}+b^{n/{2^k}})(a^{n/{2^{k-1}}}+b^{n/{2^{k-1}}})\cdots(a^{n/2}+b^{n/2})$

So is it valid to say:
$a^n - b^n$ = $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} [(a^{n/{2^x}}-b^{n/{2^x}}) \cdot\prod_{k=1}^x (a^{n/{2^k}}+b^{n/{2^k}})]$ ?

If not, why not?

If so, the limit seems to evaluate to the indeterminate form $0\cdot\infty$ (I'm not so sure about this, but Wolfram Alpha says the infinite product on the right hand side of the $\cdot$ diverges), which makes me want to use L'Hôpital's rule, but I'm not so sure how to go about that. This might have no practical use, I was just playing around with this, but I just want to know if what I'm doing actually works mathematically.

Comment: Please don't use $*$ for multiplication. In mathematics, it signifies [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution), not multiplication.

Comment: It is valid, but it's what I sometimes call a “silly limit”, because you are taking the limit of a constant. And yes, the product will diverge, since the general term goes to $2$ asymptotically. However, you might be able to fix that by dividing each factor by $2$. Then you have to compensate by multiplying the term on the left by $2^x$.

Comment: (More of a parenthetical remark: Your product notation is a bit iffy. And the $n$ plays no crucial role here; you lose no generality by chosing $n=1$.)

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful. I'm aware that you can plug in values for n, and in fact, I meant to eventually. I actually came up with this in a likely futile attempt to prove Fermat's Last (replace "a" with "c"), trying to see what happens when I plug in n=2 vs. n>2. I didn't know how to use the actual multiplication symbol with MathJax, I'll make sure not do that in the future. I will look into your suggestion further when I have more time.